# Variable battery1 symbol in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is it possible to produce a variable `battery1` sign (battery with one up slanted arrow) in `circuitikz`? There are options for `vR` and `vL` (variable resistor) but not for the `battery1`. I need it to represent a variable power supply. MWE is appended below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw   (0,-2) to[battery1] (2,-2) node [right] {Powersupply};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Generated from MWE:

[image]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

I can manually put an up arrow and position it to the middle of `battery1` sign but any shortcut like `vR` or `vL` would help.

Answer (score 3):

Just define your own component. I copy&pasted the `battery1` definition and added the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,circuitikz}

\makeatletter

\def\pgf@circ@battery2@path#1{\pgf@circ@bipole@path{battery2}{#1}}
\compattikzset{battery2/.style = {\circuitikzbasekey, /tikz/to path=\pgf@circ@battery2@path, \circuitikzbasekey/bipole/is voltage=true, v=#1}}

\ctikzset{bipoles/battery2/height/.initial=.6}
\ctikzset{bipoles/battery2/width/.initial=.3}

\pgfcircdeclarebipole{}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery2/height}}{battery2}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery2/height}}{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/battery2/width}}{
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.33\pgf@circ@res@right}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.33\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0}}
        \pgfusepath{draw}

        \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/thickness}\pgfstartlinewidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.33\pgf@circ@res@left}{.5\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.33\pgf@circ@res@left}{.5\pgf@circ@res@down}}

        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.33\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.33\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}

        \pgfsetarrowsend{latex'}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{1.5\pgf@circ@res@left}{0.9\pgf@circ@res@down}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.5\pgf@circ@res@right}{0.9\pgf@circ@res@up}}

        \pgfusepath{draw}
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw   (0,-2) to[battery2] (2,-2) node [right] {Powersupply};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: battery2]

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin for a quick reply. This macro is giving me an error  'Undefined control sequence.
l.7 \compattikzset
                  {battery2/.style...... ' What shall I do about it? Sorry if it is a trivial question. I am not an expert in tikz and writing a macro.

Comment: Did you accidentally missed adding the `\usepackage{...}` line?

Comment: No!. I copied your whole code and pasted it. I ran this MWE independently and still... same error. Wondering if there is anything wrong with my circuitikz.sty file.

Comment: Which version of `circuitikz` do you have installed? Add a `\listfiles` at the beginning of the tex file (even before `\documentclass{...}`) to get a list of all the packages used with the corresponding version numbers in the log file.

Comment: it says  circuitikz.sty    2012/12/29 The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version 0.3.0

Comment: Your circuitikz version is outdated. The current version is 0.4 Please update your TeX distribution.

Comment: Hi, can someone update this to a newer version of circuitikz?

It's failing on my machine w. xelatex and circuitikz 1.2.7 with the following error:
```
[2]
! Use of \pgf@let@token doesn't match its definition.
\pgf@let@token ...c@battery2@path#1->\pgf @circ@bi
                                                  pole@path{battery2}{#1}
l.83  \draw   (0,-2) to[battery2] (2,-2)
                                         node [right] {Powersupply};
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

and I have no idea how to fix it myself :/

Comment: Point to note: add a statement `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}` in the preamble, otherwise pgf throws an error with arrow style `latex'`.

Comment: @Floriansp1rit done (late, but I just noticed it...)

Answer (score 1):

Since `v1.4.1`, you can add "tunable arrows" to any component (see the manual, "Generic Tunable Arrows", around page 84).

```latex
\documentclass[border=2.718mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw   (0,-2) to[battery1, name=myB] (2,-2) node [right] {Powersupply};
 \ctikztunablearrow{1}{1}{60}{myB}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS/ going for a Necromancer badge...