# How do I add a resistor and add a variable voltage source?

Tags: circuitikz

I am currently trying to make this circuit, but every time I do anything it jangle up. The one that I want to add is in red.

[image]

Here are the code and the result

[image]

```
   \begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \node[op amp, noinv input up] at (0,0) (opamp) {};
    \node[ground] at (-4.69,-5.5) (ground) {};
    \draw (opamp.-) -- ++(-1.15,0) -- ++(0,-2) to[R, l_=$R_1$] ++(0,-2.5) to[short,-*] ++(-2.35,0);
    \draw (opamp.+)(-3,0)to[R, l_=$R_1$] -- ++(-3.5,0) to[V, l_=$v_\text{IN}$,] ++(0,-3) -- (ground);
    \draw (1.66,0) to[short,*-] ++(0,-2.5) to[R, l^=$R_2$, -*] ++(-4,0);
    \draw (opamp.out) to[short,-*] ++(1.5,0) node[shift={(0.6,0)}] {$v_\text{O}$};
    \draw[-latex] (opamp.up) -- ++(0,0.5) node[above] {$V_+$};
    \draw[-latex] (opamp.down) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[below] {$V_-$};

    \node[shift={(0,-0.3)}] at (opamp.-) {\scriptsize$v_-$};
    \node[shift={(0,+0.3)}] at (opamp.+) {\scriptsize$v_+$};

    \end{circuitikz}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: As I probably commented to you several times, please add the code that "jangles up", so we can identify your error and we will be able to help you learn. As it is, it seems a "please do it for me" question,, since we lack details to identify the problem.

Comment: As I see so far you not accept any of received answers. Are  any one of them fulfil your expectation and you still looking for better solutions?

Comment: Please always post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and contains the minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem you have. As for adding the arrow, maybe this can help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661331/47927

Comment: In your code, change `\draw (opamp.+)(-3,0)to[R, l_=$R_1$] -- ++(-3.5,0) to[V, l_=$v_\text{IN}$,] ++(0,-3) -- (ground);` to `\draw (opamp.+) to[R, l_=$R_1$] ++(-3.5,0) to[V, l_=$v_\text{IN}$, name=myV] ++(0,-3) -- (ground);` and add `\ctikztunablearrow{1}{1.25}{150}{myV}` before `\end{circuitikz}`.

Comment: How do I open for answer? I didn't use stack exchange until recently @Zarko

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you I will try it

Comment: To reopen, you need to edit (and add the requested information to) your question which will automatically nominate it for reopening after review.

Comment: JayBirds, I will vote for reopening, but please do as @JasperHabicht suggests and post a complete compilable snippet. `circuitikz` behavior can vary depending on the options you give in `\usepackage` (and most other packages too). Also, read https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

Your main error is to ignore the errors that you are receiving from LaTeX:

```
wth.tex|8 error| Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected.
wth.tex|8 error| Package pgf Error: No shape named `' is known.
...
```

As almost always with LaTeX, only the first error is really relevant, the other could be just related to misinterpretation trying to go past the found error.

The line in question is

```
\draw (opamp.+)(-3,0)to[R, l_=$R_1$] -- ++(-3.5,0)  [...]
```

And the error is quite clear: you need a node/coordinate after a `to` and you have a `--`.

Change that line to

```
 \draw (opamp.+) to[R, l_=$R_1$]  ++(-3.5,0) to[V, l_=$v_\text{IN}$,] ++(0,-3) -- (ground);
```

and you have:

[image]

Now, as [suggested by @Jasper Habicht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661439/how-do-i-add-a-resistor-and-add-a-variable-voltage-source#comment1645405_661439), you can add the "variable" arrow by adding a name to the generator and using the [method shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661331/47927).

The full example would be:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[op amp, noinv input up] at (0,0) (opamp) {};
    \node[ground] at (-4.69,-5.5) (ground) {};
    \draw (opamp.-) -- ++(-1.15,0) -- ++(0,-2) to[R, l_=$R_1$] ++(0,-2.5) to[short,-*] ++(-2.35,0);
    \draw (opamp.+) to[R, l_=$R_1$]  ++(-3.5,0) to[V, l_=$v_\text{IN}$, name=myV] ++(0,-3) -- (ground);
    \draw (1.66,0) to[short,*-] ++(0,-2.5) to[R, l^=$R_2$, -*] ++(-4,0);
    \draw (opamp.out) to[short,-*] ++(1.5,0) node[shift={(0.6,0)}] {$v_\text{O}$};
    \draw[-latex] (opamp.up) -- ++(0,0.5) node[above] {$V_+$};
    \draw[-latex] (opamp.down) -- ++(0,-0.5) node[below] {$V_-$};

    \node[shift={(0,-0.3)}] at (opamp.-) {\scriptsize$v_-$};
    \node[shift={(0,+0.3)}] at (opamp.+) {\scriptsize$v_+$};
    \ctikztunablearrow{1}{1.25}{150}{myV}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

PS: (See? Now the answer is much more useful because you know where the error came from! And you have an example of a "minimal working example", that you should always add to your questions)

Answer (score 1):

With except of operational amplifier with supply voltages the scheme is written in one `\draw` loop:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\IN}{\textsc{in}}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american]
\node[op amp, noinv input up]  (oa) {};
    \draw[-stealth] (oa.up)     --  ++  (0,+0.5) node[above] {$V_{+}$};
    \draw[-stealth] (oa.down)   --  ++  (0,-0.5) node[below] {$V_{-}$};
\draw
    (oa.-)  node[below] {\scriptsize $v_-$}
                -|  ++  (-0.5,-1.5) coordinate (aux)
                to [R, a=$R_1$, *-]    ++  (0,-2)
                to [short,-*]   ++  (-3,0)   node (gnd) [ground] {}
                to [V=$V_{\IN}$, name=V]    (gnd |- oa.+) %
                to [R=$R_1$]    ++  (3,0)  -- (oa.+) 
            node[above] {\scriptsize $v_+$} 
    (oa.out)    to [short,]  (oa.out |- aux)
                to [R=$R_2$]    (aux)
    (oa.out)    to [short, -o]  ++  (0.5,0) node[right] {$v_o$}
    ;
    \ctikztunablearrow[thick]{1}{1.2}{-30}{V}
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you have pasted your code twice....

Comment: @Rmano, indeed! You are right ... I remove duplicate.

Comment: Some error from the `github` server, I can't upload the figure

Comment: Yes, pictures upload is broken...